# Can one renjin R script engine instance be used by multiple threads in parallel

Tags: java, renjin

As a newbie of renjin Java library user, I plan to make use of renjin ScriptEngine to execute computation on multiple threads in parallel. It is obviously fine to initialize an renjin ScriptEngine instance on each thread and then the initialized renjin instance can be used by its belonging thread.

However, as the initialization of one renjin instance takes pretty long time, a question came across my mind: can multiple threads share one enjin ScriptEngine instance and call it in parallel?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot safely evaluate multiple R expressions concurrently using a shared RenjinSession. Technically you could if you verified that none of the R functions you're calling affect session-level state, which includes:

- Modifying the R Global environment
- Generating random numbers
- Updating Options()
- Triggering the evaluation of shared, unevaluated Promises

But all of these things are quite common amongst the R functions in the base and stats packages.

If you want to reduce the overhead of initializing new RenjinSessions, consider using [ThreadLocal](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/ThreadLocal.html?is-external=true) to cache one session per thread, or use something like the [Apache Commons Pool](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-pool/) library to maintain a pool of initialized sessions that can be quickly obtained by new threads.

Comment: Warm thanks first for your answer :) First I would say that my problem is no related to random numbers, as to the other cases u mentioned, I actually have no idea if my calculation by using renjin is related or not. But I can tell the my calculation is simple. It is only related to basic arithmetic calculation, i.e. addition, subtraction, multiplication, division, and exponential, and the calculation done with different assignment of some variables. For instance, `a=0; b=0; a+b`, `a:1;b=1; a+b` So in this case can I share one renjin ScriptEngine among different threads?

Comment: Well you can also try it, and write tests for it that verify correctness under conditions of high concurrency, but concurrency bugs can be hard to catch...

Comment: Thanks again for your hint :) btw, do u mean that one ScriptEngine isntance can have several sessions?

Comment: No, 1 ScriptEngine == 1 Session. you can instantiate multiple ScriptEngines per JVM,

Comment: Thanks again for your explanation :)